Advice for studying direct numerical simulation
I want to study direct numerical simulation.
Although I've learned about FVM, turbulence theory and spectral method for burger's equation and read some parts of review papers and materials for DNS, I couldn't understand at all.
I know many people have recommended review papers and others including John&Moin's paper.
But I couldn't understand what they've written although they are well known as kind of bible.
What I know is governing equation(Continuity and Navier Stokes eqaution) but what I read from famous materials is totally different what I know. I mean for me who is newbie of this field, I can't make heads or tails of how should I study it.
So can you guys recommend some route to study it for someone who just finished undergraduate course?
(Actually I've done my master course, but my work for master degree was close to biomedical things although my major was mechanical engineering)

Can you add the complete bibliographic information? And what you are trying to model with the direct numerical simulation

Is your problem related to understanding the PDEs, or the numerical methods?
